# Beagleboard-Xm Rev. C1 Not Booting after modifying boot.scr

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, beagleboard

I have Beagleboard-Xm Rev. C1 and ubuntu 12.04 on it,
trying to set up it with my samsung smart tv 1080p.

But when I plugged in my beagleboard-xm, TV pops-up with "unsuppported resolution, change the device's resloution" warning.

So, after days of googling I couldn't find the solution. The only thing I figured out is to change boot.scr file's dvi mode to `omapfb.mode=dvi:1280x720MR-16@60`.

After I changed it and plugged in to Beagleboard... Board is not booting up.

I think `u-boot.bin` file is not seeing `boot.scr` file.

Do anyone know any solution to that?

My `boot.scr` file:

```
    fatload mmc 0:1 0x80000000 uImage
    fatload mmc 0:1 0x81600000 uInitrd
    setenv bootargs ro elevator=noop vram=12M omapfb.mode=dvi:1280x720MR-16@60           mpurate=auto root=UUID=2ac2789a-e8d2-4382-8037-36623983a5e6 fixrtc quiet splash
    bootm 0x80000000 0x81600000
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `boot.scr` has a checksum.  You can see this if you try to `source` it.  For this you must interrupt u-boot and then enter:

```
usb start
fatload usb 0:1 $loadaddr /boot/boot.scr
source $loadaddr
```

This gives you something like

```
Bad data crc
```

At least this is the cause why modifying `boot.scr` does invalidate it.  Following URLs led me to a solution:

- http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/172395.aspx
- http://www.solid-run.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1638

Do it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install u-boot-tools
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T script -C none -n "My Boot" -d boot.txt boot.scr
```

`boot.txt` is the boot script without binary header.

Comment: I found this useful, 7.5y later, to modify the u-boot script for OpenWRT on my Espressobin. I just needed to change the arch argument to `-A arm64`. Thanks!